# How to edit running total fields in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a crystal report which has a running total field, i want to look what is the formula that running total field is using? I have never used crystal reports am debugging with that now.

> In other words how do i edit existing running total fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the left hand side of the screen should be the Field Explorer.  In that list is a group called 'Running Total Fields'.  If you expand that list you'll see all running total fields for a report.  If you right click one of those fields one of your options is 'Edit'.

The edit box has a whole bunch of different options.  Summarizing a field by sum, or average, or minimum, maximum, etc. etc. etc.

You can also just find where the running total is being used in the report and right click the field its self to bring up the 'Edit' GUI.

If you're asking about code at a deeper level than this GUI, that is not revealed to the end user outside of this GUI/Wizard style format.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see anything below Running Total Fields and when i right click i see New and Refresh options, is that means there is no running total usage in that report?

Comment: Yes, that is what that means.  If the report contains what appears to be a "running total" it is likely being calculated prior to being given to Crystal by the codebase or the database that is providing the dataset.

Comment: Ok am having tough time to find how a total value is calculated as i see that in the crystal report but i don't see the code in DB and front end app.

Comment: Right clicking the field should give you clues about what type of field it is.  It might be a parameter, or a formula based on the record.  Of course, if it is a formula it should appear in the formula field list.